# Have the function and property of one control in many other forms

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I have properties and functions of form control on many other forms. For one form I did like this:

```
flashForm flashForm = new flashForm();
```

and for the form loaded this:

```
        flashForm.SHOW();
```

and in click of buttons this:

```
  flashForm.MOVIE = @"D:\football scoreboard project\football scoreboard\footballscoreb    \quran.swf";
    flashForm.Controls["axShockwaveFlash1"].Show();
```

but for other forms I cant use first line of code because it make a new object of that form not  in the form I want

Comment: You want the same `axShockwaveFlash1` to be shown in other forms, or a *new instance* similar to current `axShockwaveFlash1` in other forms?

Comment: i want to have the property of the form that is opened before.

Comment: Looks like you need to create user control, which you can reuse on many forms. Is this what you want?

Comment: Just the property `MOVIE`? or even the method `flashForm.Controls["axShockwaveFlash1"].Show()`?

Comment: MOVIE is a variable that i defined like this to set the value of axShocwavflash1:public string MOVIE 
        {
            get { return this.axShockwaveFlash1.Movie; }
            set { this.axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = value; }
        }

Comment: i dont know what really "user controll" is.

Comment: "i dont know what really "user control" is" - this is exactly your problem, I think

Comment: no i meant "i dont understand your solution". :d

Comment: @virtouso looks like you would hardly understand my solution, it's a pity for me.

Comment: @virtouso - a solution come from the problem. Using your description we hardly can understand your problem. I am guessing is that you want to have many forms displaying some movie control with different movies. This calls for creation of `UserControl` "Movie" and reusing this control. Or, you asking about telling "Movie" form to be manipulated by other forms. Please formulate your question and describe your problem - there are plenty of experts here to help you solve it. But so far I don't see concrete well described issue.

Comment: i have a form that i want to change it properties from other forms. if i want to get accses to that form i have to write like this: flashform flashForm=new flashForm(); but it makes a new instance o that form but i want to change the property of form that is already opened. i cant explain it better.

Comment: Let me give you one scenario, this is design pattern called Singleton. It ensures, you always work with one and only one instance. And the call will be `MovieForm.Instance.MyProperty = "property data"`. Can you handle researching ".Net Singleton pattern"?

Comment: ok. thanks for your help. ill search it.

Comment: I just posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `tons` of ways to *communicate* between forms. I guess your situation is you have some control to load and play the movie in some form. I would like to introduce this mechanism in which the control doesn't need to know about the display, it just fires some event to notify that `I want to display this movie`, the display form also doesn't need to be held/referred in any class, it just needs to subscribe the event and show/change the movie whenever the event is fired. Looks like we need some *static event* here. You can define this static event in your main UI class, something like this:

```
public partial class MainUI : Form {
   //...
   public class RequireShowMovieEventArgs : EventArgs {
     public string MoviePath {get; private set;}
     public RequireShowMovieEventArgs(string moviePath){
       MoviePath = moviePath;
     }
   }
   public delegate void RequireShowMovieEventHandler(object sender, RequireShowMovieEventArgs e);
   public static event RequireShowMovieEventHandler RequireShowMovie;
   //...
}
//just fire the event when you want to show/change the movie
RequireShowMovieEventHandler handler = MainUI.RequireShowMovie;
if(handler != null) handler(yourObject, new MainUI.RequireShowMovieEventArgs(@"D:\football scoreboard project\football scoreboard\footballscoreb    \quran.swf"));
//Your display form (which you call flashForm)
public class FlashForm : Form {
 public FlashForm(){
   MainUI.RequireShowMovie += RequiresShowMovieHandler;
   Disposed += (s,e) => {
      MainUI.RequireShowMovie -= RequiresShowMovieHandler;
   };
 }
 private void RequireShowMovieHandler(object sender, MainUI.RequireShowMovieEventArgs e){
   MOVIE = e.MoviePath;
   axShockwaveFlash1.Show();      
 }
 //....
}
```

**NOTE**: the `yourObject` in my code above is whatever you want, even `null`. However you should consider passing in the actual control which fires the event (such as a Button).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get away with `singleton`:

```
public class MovieForm : Form
{

    private MovieForm _instance;

    private MovieForm()...

    public static MovieForm Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null) _instance = new MovieForm();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public void Play()...
    public void Play(Url movieUrl)...
    public void Pause()...
    public void Stop()...
}
```

Usage:

```
Movieform.Instance.Show();
Movieform.Instance.Play();
```